# What is the difference between the + operator and std.mergePatch in Jsonnet?

Tags: merge, operators, jsonnet

Jsonnet's [`std.mergePatch`](https://jsonnet.org/ref/stdlib.html#mergePatch) implements [RFC7396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7396), but in my naive testing I didn't find a different between the way it behaved and the `+` operator; e.g. the `+` operator respects `x+` syntax. `std.mergePatch` is [implemented in Jsonnet](https://github.com/google/jsonnet/blob/master/stdlib/std.jsonnet#L1268) itself, which seems to imply that it is different than the `+` operator, which I'm assuming is a builtin.

What is different about the semantics of these two ways of merging?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Jsonnet's `+` and `std.mergePatch` are completely different operations. The `+` operator operates only on a single level and `std.mergePatch` traverses the object recursively and merges the nested objects. It's easiest to explain with an example:

```
local foo = { a: {b1: {c1: 42}}},
      bar = { a: {b2: {c2: 2}}};
foo + bar
```

Output:

```
{
   "a": {
      "b2": {
         "c2": 2
      }
   }
}
```

Note that the `bar.a` completely replaced `foo.a`. With `+` all fields in the second object override the fields in the first object. Compare that with the result of using `std.mergePatch(foo, bar)`.

```
{
   "a": {
      "b1": {
         "c1": 42
      },
      "b2": {
         "c2": 2
      }
   }
}
```

Since both `foo` and `bar` have a field `a`, is is merged and the final results contains both `b1` and `b2`.

So to reiterate, `+` is a "flat" operation which overrides the fields of the first object with the fields of the second object.

This is not the end of the story, though. You mentioned `field+: value` syntax and I will try to explain what it really does. In Jsonnet `+` is not just overwriting, but inheritance in OO sense. It creates an object which is the result of the second object inheriting from the first one. It's a bit exotic to have an operator for that – in all mainstream languages such relationships are statically defined. In Jsonnet, when you do `foo + bar`, the `bar` object has access to stuff from `foo` through `super`:

```
{ a: 2 } + { a_plus_1: super.a + 1}
```

This results in:

```
{
   "a": 2,
   "a_plus_1": 3
}
```

You can use this feature to merge the fields deeper inside:

```
{ a: {b: {c1: 1}, d: 1}} +
{ a: super.a + {b: {c2: 2} } }
```

Resulting in:

```
{
   "a": {
      "b": {
         "c2": 2
      },
      "d": 1
   }
}
```

This is a bit repetitive, though (it would be annoying if the field name was longer). So we have a nice syntax sugar for that:

```
{ a: {b: {c1: 1} , d: 1}} +
{ a+: {b: {c2: 2}} }
```

Please note that in these examples we only did the merging for one particular field we chose. We still replaced the value of `a.b`. This is much more flexible, because in many cases you can't just naively merge all stuff inside (sometimes a nested object is "atomic" and should be replaced completely).

The version in `+:` works in the same way as the version with `super`. The subtle difference is that `+:` actually translates to something like `if field in super then super.field + val else val`, so it also returns the same value when `super` is not provided at all or doesn't have this particular field. For example `{a +: {b: 42}}` evaluates just fine to `{a: { b: 42 }}`.

*Mandatory sermon: while `+` is very powerful, please don't abuse it. Consider using using functions instead of inheritance when you need to parameterize something.*